# ASP.NET Core React Application returning 400 with no message on GET

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server, javascriptservices

My application was working fine, and then the next day I ran it (dotnet run) and it started returning 400 for all requests, with no message. I can reproduce the issue on various machines; however, some of my coworkers cannot.

I am unable to get my code to break on the exception - all break points seem to lead to a successful response. I've tried changing my debug level and configuring logging in Kestrel using:

```
.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
                {
                    logging.AddConsole();
                    logging.AddDebug();
                    logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
                })
```

I also tried adding some middleware per this post: https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-middleware-to-log-requests-and-responses-in-asp-net-core/

This did not give me anything more than it is returning a 400.

**How can I get more about the error so that I understand what is causing the underlying 400?**

What I'm seeing:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET [my url]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 1044.473ms 400
```

Some obvious culprits that I have ruled out:

- Authentication is occurring successfully.
- No changes ran on my machine in the mean time aside from an anti-virus definition update.
- I did run an npm install, but my coworkers did as well so we should be on the same versions of everything.
- My git status is clean so there shouldn't be any hidden changes in my local repo, and I tried it on two other clean machines.

Comment: turn up logging level.

Comment: reboot, `dotnet restore` and retry

Comment: Have you verified (e.g. using your browser network monitor) that the response body is really empty? Model validation would add detailed errors here. (env = Development?). What happens if you add a very simple Action for Http GET requests?

Comment: Daniel, I tried turning the logging up to verbose in the config, but I didn't get any more info - is there a better place to do this?

Comment: No Refunds No Returns, I definitely already tried that - I've even set it up on two other computers and gotten the same result. I think I just need a better way to debug at this point.

Comment: Hi Christoph, yes I verified in Fiddler that the response body is empty. I am using the React project in visual studio, so for the index route, it's not served from an action but as a static file from the public folder. My actions for things like auth seem to be working fine.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns 's comment above was the only solution that worked for me

Comment: wooot! I <3 SO.